# How ETL tool Fast Load to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, oledb, alteryx

When I use Fast Load to SQL Server from ETL tool like SSIS or Altery I see below running on SQL Server

```
insert bulk <TableName>(Column1 datatype, Column2 datatype, ......., column datatype)
with (TABLOCK, ROWS_PER_BATCH = 418397672, CHECK_CONSTRAINTS)
```

How does SSIS/Alteryx make above insert bulk call? Does SQL Server expose some APIs for ETL tools to call?

I found below documentation and syntax but not much detail.

[image: INSERT BULK Syntax]

[image: Brief Detail on INSERT BULK]

Answer (score 0):

The docs you cited seem pretty old, you may want to look at the [latest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (even tho I didn't find something useful).

`BULK INSERT` is meant to import data from files ONLY and can be used from SSMS.
It's also an API that may or may not be supported/used by the different drivers and I've found it [referenced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/use-bulk-copy-api-batch-insert-operation?view=sql-server-ver16) as
*Bulk Copy API for batch insert operations*.

I didn't find any "global" page about it (like a list of drivers with support yes/no), therefore I think you will have to look into the documentation of your driver.